# Android ratingbar doesn't update

Tags: android, user-interface, android-studio, ratingbar

I've made a ratingbar in my app which uses a custom style, using my own stars.

My ratingbar is defined as followed:

```
 <RatingBar
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="15dp"
           android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
           android:numStars="10"
           android:stepSize="1"
           android:rating="10"
           android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
           android:layout_below="@id/feedbackTable"
           android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ratingText"
           android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
           style="@style/starBar" />
```

The style that I use in styles.xml is:

```
<style name="starBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/ratingstars</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">22dip</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">22dip</item>
    </style>
```

With ratingstars.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/background" android:drawable="@drawable/ratingstars_full_empty" />
    <item android:id="@+id/secondaryProgress" android:drawable="@drawable/ratingstars_full_empty" />
    <item android:id="@+id/progress" android:drawable="@drawable/ratingstars_full_filled" />
</layer-list>
```

When I adjust the android:rating it shows the correct amount of stars filled and being empty in the preview. However, using my emulator or real device the bar stays completely filled with stars (10/10). I've tried adjusting it programmatically by using the following piece of code:

```
 ratingbar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                Log.d("rating", rating+"");
                ratingbar.setRating(rating);
            }
        });
```

Now the log from logcat shows actually that rating IS changed, but the bar does not visually update itself with e.g. 6 stars being full, and 4 empty and I have no clue why.

The drawables are correct as the preview also shows it correct, so what can cause this?

**Edit:**

This is ratingstars_full_filled.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star" />

    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star" />

    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/star" />

</selector>
```

And here is ratingstars_full_empty.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty" />

    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty" />

    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty" />

</selector>
```

Comment: " Now the log from logcat shows actually that rating IS changed, but the bar does not visually update itself with e.g. 6 stars being full, and 4 empty and I have no clue why."  ======> This means you may not be correctly updating the rating bar. So you just check whether the rating bar rating is correctly changed at your required area of the code!

Comment: Shouldn't IDs start with '@android:id' instead of '@+id' in ratingstars.xml?

Comment: No, since it is the first occurence in the xml file of the ids

Answer (score 3):

You should change the id attribute in ratingstars.xml from `"@+id/..."` to `"@android:id/..."`, since the resource is part of the android system, and already defined in the default android progress drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background" android:drawable="@drawable/ratingstars_full_empty" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress" android:drawable="@drawable/ratingstars_full_empty" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress" android:drawable="@drawable/ratingstars_full_filled" />
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's not a problem with the listener being called, but rather just the custom `android:progressDrawable` style attribute you're applying to it. My guess is that the  drawable you're using is doing unexpected things. Try removing `style="@style/starBar"` from your RatingBar and see if things are working as expected. If so, that's your problem

Comment: If I use the default, it indeed works. Now the question what casues the disruption using a custom style?

Comment: I'd take a look at what the default looks like: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/drawable/ratingbar_full.xml

and keep digging to see how your drawables line up with the default. For example, what do these look like:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/drawable/ratingbar_full_empty.xml

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/drawable/ratingbar_full_filled.xml

Comment: I do have these in my drawable map... do you think the _full_empty suffix matters? I'm going to test this in a moment, will come back to it.

Comment: The name shouldn't matter, but you could post what your star_empty.xml and star.xml drawable files look like

Comment: It's a bit odd that all the states of your selector have the same drawable, have you tried providing different drawables for pressed vs focused etc?

Comment: All examples and tutorial use for the empty star the same drawable. See http://kozyr.zydako.net/2010/05/23/pretty-ratingbar/ for a popular example